# Which translation of "Mongolia" is most suitable for everyday use?

Tags: translation

Which translation of "Mongolia" is most suitable for everyday conversation?

The Japanese edition of Wikipedia's entry on Mongolia has the article title of [モンゴル国](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AB%E5%9B%BD), Wiktionary [translates](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mongolia#English) it as "モンゴル" and "蒙古", and [weblio](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/Mongolia) has amongst others "モンゴリア", which is also what someone suggested I use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For everyday use, it is definitely 「モンゴル」.  I would be lying if I answered otherwise.

「モンゴル[国]{こく}」 sounds too formal for everyday use.

「モンゴリア」 is ***very*** rare despite what you have been told by that someone.

Comment: and 蒙古 is usually found in compound words ("蒙古斑", etc) and perhaps in historical contexts.